# Cannot Install into Virtual Environment

Tags: python, linux, virtual-machine, virtualenv, apt-get

I have a virtual environment I have created on an Ubuntu virtal machine I am hosting on a windows PC. I intend to replicate my virtual machine in my virtal environment on the virtual machine. However, when trying to install modules to the VE I get a messgae saying that they are already installed - they're not installed in the VE but are on the VM. I thought when set active the VE would have no context of the VM which hosts it?

I have downloaded virtualenvironment  `sudo pip install virtualenv`   and then created a virtual environment `sudo virtualenv virtual_environment`. I then set the virtual environment to active `source virtual_environment/bin/activate`

When I try and do an apt-get install I get the message 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 202 not upgraded despite the fact I have no modules whatsoever on the VE.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: don't use sudo to create a virtualenv and why are you using apt-get inside the virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting a bit confused about what virtualenv does. It is only for isolating Python files and libraries (those you install with `pip install`). It does nothing for your operating system files (those you install with `apt-get`).

If you want to create a re-usable container of operating system files (with `apt-get`) then look instead at something like Docker.

Comment: thanks for the docker suggestion - this is what i had in mind and thouhgt virtualenv would do